# Navigate through past commands in C shell?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, csh

For a certain assignment I am required to use a C shell. I already have `csh` up and going.

However, I've noticed that usually when I press the `up` and `down` keys on bash terminal I see past commands I've used. But on C terminal I just see (for example) `^[[A` when I press the `up` key, and `^[[B` when I press the down key.

Is there any way to fix csh to list previous commands when I press the up and down keys?

By the way, this is just for the minor convenience of not having to retype the entire ./script filename command everytime I want to test a script on a text file.

Comment: Which particular `csh` implementation do you have? `tcsh` appears to provide history out-of-the-box; the original (Berkeley?) `csh` maybe not.

Comment: i just used `sudo apt-get install csh` and went with what was there. So probably the original Berkeley csh.

Comment: If you're permitted to use the [TENEX csh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh) (`sudo apt-get install tcsh`) then I think you will find that it has the history scrolling feature that you want. The original `csh` does have [history expansion](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-71) - but I don't know if it can be configured with to scroll through commands using arrow keys like you want.